# How to set Attributes of Parent Window with button click in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm still fairly new to WPF so I don't really know how to express myself, nevertheless:

I got a "Window.xaml" which hosts another window "ReportGenerator.xaml" in a Frame:

```
<Metro:MetroWindow x:Class="ROGERS.Windows.Window"
                   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                   xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                   xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                   xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ROGERS.Windows"
                   xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:ROGERS.Windows.ViewModels"
                   xmlns:Views="clr-namespace:ROGERS.Windows.Views"
                   xmlns:Metro="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
                   xmlns:MetroIcons="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/iconpacks"
                   mc:Ignorable="d"
                   Title="ROGERS"
                   TitleAlignment="Center"
                   Icon="App.ico"
                   IconBitmapScalingMode="HighQuality"
                   Height="800" 
                   Width="1440"
                   ShowIconOnTitleBar="True"
                   WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
                   WindowTitleBrush= "#0c3868"
                   BorderBrush="#0c3868"
                   BorderThickness="1,1,1,1">

    <Metro:MetroWindow.DataContext>
        <ViewModels:WindowViewModel />
    </Metro:MetroWindow.DataContext>

    <Frame Source="Views/ReportGenerator.xaml"/>
</Metro:MetroWindow>
```

I would like to set the Opacity of the "Window.xaml" (Parent) by pressing a Button used in the "ReportGenerator.xaml". Basically in the corresponding "ReportGenerator.xaml.cs" i would like to do something along the lines of `Window.Opacity = 0.25` or so on. But I don't know how to access the Opacity Attribute of the Window.xaml.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
Window yourParentWindow = (Window)MetroWindow.GetWindow(this);
yourParentWindow.Opacity = 0.25;
```